# How to find the commit of rustc used to bootstrap rustc master

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build Rust from source. From the stage0.txt I can see that the rustc used is `beta-2016-04-13` and the `rustc_key` is `c2743eb4`.

How do I find out which commit beta-2016-04-13 represents?

And if I build rustc beta will the rustc_key be a different one?

Comment: Why do you need to figure this out? I've never needed this to build from source. On OS X it's just the normal `./configure && make`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually do not need to figure out which rustc commit it is. Since [Rust is bootstrapped from the previous version](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/32942), you can simply use the last beta (or stable in the future, probably after the next release).

Quoting Alex Crichton in the PR that changed this:

> This commit removes all infrastructure from the repository for our so-called
>   snapshots to instead bootstrap the compiler from stable releases.

---

> And if I build rustc beta will the rustc_key be a different one?

No, you can build anything up to and including (meaning the beta) the next rustc version with that key.

Comment: *you can simply use the last beta* — is there something active that a programmer needs to do here? The build infrastructure has always performed the download for me...

Comment: no, that still works out of the box. I'm assuming @dvc wants to do that downloading manually?

Comment: I'm trying to update - somewhat usuccessfully sofar - the package for nixos, a src based linux distribution

Comment: If the beta version doesn't matter and rustc_key is the same for all beta versions, why am I getting `#[feature] may not be used on the beta release channel` when trying to compile master? or should this be a new question? =P

Comment: the key belongs to the last stable + the beta that turned into that stable. The new beta can't be used until there's a stable. So to compile 1.10, you need stable 1.9 or beta 1.9, not beta 1.10

Comment: I'm still confused. I'm getting `configure: using rustc at: /nix/store/f8rsfvsfxncmh5453cspby891yy3r71y-rustc-1.9.0 with version: rustc 1.9.0` and `#[feature] may not be used on the stable release channel`

Comment: how are you passing the bootstrap key? There are the `RUSTC_BOOTSTRAP_KEY` and ´CFG_BOOTSTRAP_KEY´ env vars. I'm not sure which one (or if both) need to be set.

Comment: I finally managed to build master :). The env variables didn't take effect. I think they are overwritten automatically. I solved it by patching stage0.txt to look like the one in the beta branch. Do you think it's ok to submit a PR or shall I leave it up to the pro's to update stage0.txt when they're ready?

Comment: yea, leave it to them. their own setup might differ from yours.